# Using AWS SDK (JS) for s3.selectObjectContent gives error on 'on' keyword

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm using AWS SDK for Javascript version `2.730.0` (latest at time of writing) in a Typescript file in Node.JS.

I'm using the `selectObjectContent` operation to query a CSV file, and following the [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#selectObjectContent-property) in the documentation I have this block:

```
import * as S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
const s3 = new S3();

...

s3.selectObjectContent(params, (err, data) => {
   if (!err){
      data.Payload.on('data', (event) => {

         // Do something with returned records

      });
   }
});
```

The line `data.Payload.on('data', (event) => {` is giving this error in the linter:

> Property 'on' does not exist on type 'EventStream<{ Records?: RecordsEvent; Stats?: StatsEvent; Progress?: ProgressEvent; Cont?: ContinuationEvent; End?: EndEvent; }>'.

What do I need to change for `on` to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem myself. Found this problem post on another forum:

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/aws/aws-sdk-js/3525/725076849

It does not explicitly show code to solve the problem but based on the information, I solved it as follows:

```
import { ReadStream } from "fs";
const eventStream = data.Payload as ReadStream;
eventStream.on("data", ({ Records, Stats, Progress, Cont, End }: ...
```

TypeScript no longer complains.